# continuity of $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have to prove that the function given below is continuous in $\mathbb R^2$:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$f(x,y)$=
\begin{cases}  e^{-\text(\frac{1}{|x-y|})} & \text{if $x\neq y$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x=y$} \end{cases}

I have just started learning continuity in two/more dimensions ,so please help how to prove that the function is continuous on any path I take in 2 dimensions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the function is continuous at all points of the form $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $a\neq b$. So you need to check continuity at points of the form $(a,a)$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

In particular you have to prove that

$$\lim_{h,k \to 0} f(a+h,a+k) = f(a,a) = 0$$

If $h=k$ you have $f(a+h,a+k) = 0$, so you can consider $h \neq k$. Now

$$f(a+h,a+k) = \exp \left(- \frac{1}{|h-k|} \right) \to 0$$

since $h, k \to 0 $ implies that $ |h-k| \to 0$.

Comment: how did you conclude that function is continuous at all points of the form $(a,b)\in R^2$ with $a\neq b$.

Comment: It follows by continuity of the composition of two functions. $(a,b) \mapsto |a-b|$ is continuous everywhere, while $h \mapsto \exp \left( - \frac{1}{h} \right)$ is continuous for $h \neq 0$. So, for $a \neq b$ you have $|a-b| \neq 0$, hence continuity of $f$ in $(a,b)$.