# Prove that $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that $$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}  e^{\frac{-1}{|x-y|}} &\text{for } x\neq y\\
          0  &\text{ for  } x =  y\end{cases}$$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2}$. How much $proof$ has to go into showing that when $x \neq y$ $f(x,y)$ is continuous. It seems clearly true for since we have the constraint that $x\neq y$. For the $f(x,y) =0$ case where can I take this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [continuity of $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb R^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958149/continuity-of-fx-y-in-mathbb-r2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

$f(x,y)=g(x-y)$ where

$$g(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{\vert x \vert}}$$ for $x \neq 0$ and $g(0)=0$.

$g$ is continuous as $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)=0$. Finally $f$ is continuous being the composition of two continuous maps.